# GWT/RequestFactory : ValidationTools work in DevMode, but not when deployed webapp

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I started with gwt, and my problem is as follows :

- I have a project in gwt, and when I run the application DevMode, all work fine (Validation Tool do is stuff : "*ensure that the mapping of proxy properties and context methods to their domain types is valid*")
- When I compile the application, and deploy the war in my application server (Tomcat), mapping does not seem to occur
- In the deploy webapp, when I fire a request, `the onFailure(ServerFailure error)` is call, and the error is `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ServerFailure`

I follow this instruction ( http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation ) for configure my IDE (Eclipse).

My question is :

- About this link, I need to run the command line (given that I've already set my IDE) ?
- Has anyone ever had this kind of problem ?
- Do you have a track to provide me with my research ?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

**edit :**
My script Ant is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="Jaguards" basedir="." default="default">
    <property name="tomcat" value="/home/gilles/Logiciels/apache-tomcat-7.0.34" />
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="war/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="war" />
    <property name="unitcache" value="gwt-unitCache" />
    <property name="gwt.module.name" value="fr/janua/Jaguards_gwt" />

    <target name="default" depends="1-clear-cache, 2-export-jar, 4-buildwar,5-deploy">
    </target>

    <target name="1-clear-cache">
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${unitcache}">
                <exclude name="*.svn"/>
            </fileset>
        </delete>
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="war/jaguards_gwt">
                <include name="*.cache.html"/>
                <include name="*.gwt.rpc"/>
                <exclude name=".svn"/>
            </fileset>
        </delete>
    </target>

    <target name="2-export-jar" description="exportation des sources en jar">
        <jar destfile="${lib.dir}/Jaguards.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="3-compile">
        <echo message="Do GWT Compile Project..."></echo>
    </target>

    <target name="4-buildwar">
        <war basedir="war" destfile="jaguards-0.1.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
            <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
                <include name="**/gwt-servlet.jar" />
                <include name="**/classes/**" />
                <exclude name="**/gwt-dev.jar" />
                <exclude name="**/javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar" />
            </webinf>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="5-deploy">
        <delete dir="${tomcat}/work/Catalina/localhost/jaguards-0.1"></delete>
        <delete dir="${tomcat}/webapps/jaguards-0.1"></delete>
        <delete file="${tomcat}/webapps/jaguards-0.1.war"></delete>
        <copy file="jaguards-0.1.war" todir="${tomcat}/webapps/" />
    </target>
</project>
```

To summarize :

1. First step, my ant script clear cache files
2. My ant script export a Jar of project
3. I compile project with my IDE (Eclipse)
4. My ant script build a war
5. My ant script deploy my war file in tomcat

Comment: How are you packaging your WAR?

Comment: I package my WAR file with an ant script :

`<target name="buildwar">
<war basedir="war" destfile="namefile.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
<exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
<webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
<include name="**/*.jar" />
<include name="**/gwt-servlet.jar" />
<include name="**/classes/**" />
<exclude name="**/gwt-dev.jar" />
<exclude name="**/javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar" />
</webinf>
</war>
</target>`

(sorry for the format)

Comment: And the classes are compiled by? (maybe edit your question and paste your Ant script in there)

Comment: My classes are compiled by my "plugin for eclipse" (GWT Compile Project...). Thank you for your advice, I'll edit my post to stick my ant script.

Comment: Note: by "compiled classes", I mean the content of `**/classes/**`, i.e. `javac`, not the GWT compilation: `ValidationTool` is a server-side thing.

Comment: Ah, oki. My classes is automaticly compiled by Eclipse. For deploy a project, is it a good practice to compile my classes myself (with arguments) ? (sorry for my incompetence, I have only 4 months of practice by himself with gwt)

Comment: From your comments, creating my war was not good. I'll re-write it, inspiring me to this link: http://www.rubiconred.com/blog/build-package-a-gwt-app-to-war-using-ant/
Thanks a lot ! :)